# ffmpeg watermark logo with hardcode subtitle

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

Hi I want to add watermark png image to video with hardcode substitle .srt file at same time what changes i should do the following line

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -threads 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset veryslow -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=0:0 [out]"  output.mp4
```

Comment: "Questions about using the ffmpeg command line tool should be asked on Super User."

Comment: superuser ! what you mean ?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard You should mention that the question can be flagged for migration to avoid cross-posting and possible duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You can hardcode subtitles into the video [with the `subtitles` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20burn%20subtitles%20into%20the%20video). The best way to do what you want is with a filterchain, which passes the video through the chain (so the output of the overlay filter becomes the input of the subtitles filter). Filters in the chain are separated by commas. This should not be confused with a filtergraph, which consists of one or more filters or filterchains, separated by semicolons.

I've removed the whitespace and shortened the labels so that this example will fit without side-scrolling. If you type this into a command prompt, you should do it on a single line, removing the back-slashes and newlines:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -threads 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset veryslow \
-vf "movie=watermark.png[wm];[in][wm]overlay=0:0,subtitles=subtitle.srt[out]" \
output.mp4
```

Personally, I prefer using a complex filtergraph rather that the movie filter, when I have multiple inputs:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i watermark.png -threads 0 -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset veryslow \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0,subtitles=subtitle.srt[out]" \
-map "[out]" -map 0:a output.mp4
```

Note that the second one will use *all* audio streams from input.mkv, which may or may not be what you want. If you don't want any audio, remove the `-map 0:a`; if you want a specific stream, see the [map](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Advanced-options) and [stream specifiers](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Stream-specifiers-1) documentation.